# Force INSERT only via stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Using SQL Server 2008, is there a way to allow inserts to a table only via a stored procedure, and if so how?

**EDIT:**
The best way to go is probably Martin Smith's suggestion to use an [INSTEAD OF INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089.aspx) trigger. The direct answer to this question is marc_s' one with GRANT and DENY, though it won't limit some user accounts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stored Procedure and Permissions - Is EXECUTE enough?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815411/stored-procedure-and-permissions-is-execute-enough)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just do not grant any database users (and your "public" role) the INSERT permission on the table.

Grant those users the permission to execute the INSERT stored proc - that way, they can call the stored proc, but they cannot directly insert any data into the underlying table.

```
DENY INSERT ON dbo.YourTable TO PUBLIC
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.InsertDataProc TO PUBLIC
```

Comment: This is the *only* way... assuming that the connection is not db_owner or sysadmin...

Comment: This doesn't work for me.   I get `The INSERT permission was denied on the object...` even when I am executing a stored procedure that does the INSERT.   I am using SQL 2012.   Ah, I have just learned that that's because this answer will not work if the INSERT is done with dynamic SQL inside the proc.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, getting `ERROR:  permission denied for table user`

Answer (score 6):

Deny `INSERT` permission on the table, and grant EXECUTE permission on the stored procedure.

Answer (score 4):

What is the motivation for the question? Is it because the stored procedure contains certain logic that you are relying on being carried out whenever data is inserted? If so you might want to use a trigger to encapsulate this logic.

If that isn't suitable and you want to  prevent even people with sysadmin permissions from inserting to the table directly, well you can't, but you can make sure that it doesn't happen accidentally by using an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger that raises an error and rolls back unless a certain `CONTEXT_INFO` value is set then clears the `CONTEXT_INFO` (Your stored procedure could set this to the expected value)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214382%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use permissions (grants). Create the SP and grant the `execute` right to the user or role in question. Then deny the `insert` right on the table an you should be all set.