# User can delete rows from a table by calling a procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm getting somewhat confused with SQL Server security

- we have a **login** and a **user**: `test`
- we have a **table**: `dbo.tblSessionFilter`

User test has no select and no delete permission on this table (I tested this!!)

- Then we have a **procedure**:

  ```
  create procedure dbo.procFilter_Clear with execute as caller 
  as
     delete from dbo.tblSessionfilter 
     where spid = @@SPID
  ```

User test has execute right on this procedure.

And now, user test **can call** this procedure and **can delete** entries from the table; although he has no direct delete access on the table, and the procedure is `execute as caller` !

How is that possible ?

Is it probably because procedure and table are in the same schema?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815411/stored-procedure-and-permissions-is-execute-enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Ownership Chains](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> When multiple database objects access each other sequentially, the sequence is known as a chain. Although such chains do not independently exist, when SQL Server traverses the links in a chain, SQL Server evaluates permissions on the constituent objects differently than it would if it were accessing the objects separately.

and,

> When an object is accessed through a chain, SQL Server first compares the owner of the object to the owner of the calling object. This is the previous link in the chain. **If both objects have the same owner, permissions on the referenced object are not evaluated.**

(**My emphasis**)