# How to allow insert through stored procedure only?

Tags: mysql, sql, security, stored-procedures, insert

I have the MySQL version of [this question for SQL-Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2533493/4233593)

I'm running mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.49, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

I have created a user with only this permission:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'p@55w0rd';
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbname.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

I have created this procedure on `dbname`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE seed_database()
this_procedure:BEGIN

  INSERT INTO `dbtable` VALUES (1,'data');

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

But when I login with that user and try to `CALL seed_database();`, I get:

> ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1: INSERT command denied to user 'username'@'localhost' for table 'dbtable'

I'm trying to follow [the principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) by only allowing a user to execute stored procedures. I don't want to give a user privilege to directly INSERT on a table with the obvious `GRANT INSERT ON dbname.dbtable TO 'username'@'localhost';`, in case the credentials are compromised and because I have some complex logic inside the stored procedure that produces inputs to be stored (represented by hard-coded data in the example `(1,'data')`) that I don't want the user generating and inserting directly. But I would like for them to use the stored procedure to accomplish the same objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you read up on [definer's rights procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html). You should be able to define your procedure to run as a privileged user, then `GRANT EXECUTE` to unprivileged users:

```
GRANT INSERT ON TABLE dbtable
  TO 'privileged_user'@'localhost';

CREATE
    DEFINER = 'privileged_user'@'localhost'
  PROCEDURE seed_database()
    BEGIN

      INSERT INTO `dbtable` VALUES (1,'data');

    END;

GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE dbname.seed_database
  TO 'unprivileged_user'@'localhost';
```

DISCLAIMER: I'm not set up to test this at the moment, but it should work.

By default, MySQL executes stored procedures with "definer's rights," that is, with the privileges of the person who is creating the stored procedure. This means that this user must have privileges on  all the data objects the procedure accesses. When the `DEFINER` clause is specified in the `CREATE FUNCTION / PROCEDURE`, MySQL will instead execute the procedure with the privileges of the user named in the `DEFINER` clause. In both cases, as long as the *definer* has privileges on the data objects, the *invoker* only needs privilege on the procedure itself.

Invoker's or definer's rights can also be specified explicitly, as in

```
CREATE PROCEDURE seed_database()
  SQL SECURITY DEFINER
  BEGIN
    ...
```

Specifying `SECURITY DEFINER` without a `DEFINER =` clause causes the definer to default to the person actually executing the `CREATE` statement. This is the same as not specifying either clause.

Specifying `SECURITY INVOKER` causes MySQL to execute with the privileges of the person *using* the stored procedure. This means that the invoker must have privileges on the procedure *and* on all data objects the procedure accesses. This may be done, for example, with administrative routines so that a user who isn't allowed to muck about in the system tables also can't use a *procedure* that mucks about in the system tables even if accidentally granted access to that procedure.

Comment: thanks! that was the required reading I needed. after doing some testing, I realized that it did work the first time around when creating the procedure as root. but I had confounded some things by trying to create a test environment where the user could alter, drop, and create procedures. I had naively assumed all SPs run at elevated permissions. so they could recreate the procedure, but obviously allowing insert permissions would be a security vulnerability. thank you

Comment: Quite welcome. I'm adding a little info on invoker's vs. definer's rights to my answer for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: with regards to ***By default**, MySQL executes stored procedures with "invoker's rights,"* this may have changed in recent versions, but for 5.5 *The SQL SECURITY characteristic can be DEFINER or INVOKER ... **The default** value is DEFINER ... The default DEFINER value is the user who executes the CREATE PROCEDURE* as is consistent with my previous comment observing insert was allowed with only execution rights to user when sp defined by root (completely omitting the SQL SECURITY DEFINER and DEFINER clauses)

Comment: Egad, you're right. I must have had something else in mind. I shall correct myself forthwith.